# how to implement onTouchListener?

Tags: android

I have a toggleButton that I wish to set an onTouchListener on. I am getting some errors however so I don't think I'm doing this right.

I have declared my button.

```
private ToggleButton pushBtn;
```

I have set my activity to implement View.onTouchListener.

```
public class InCallActivity extends SherlockFragmentActivity implements  View.OnTouchListener {
```

In onCreate I have written:

```
pushBtn = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.PTT_button3);
pushBtn.setOnTouchListener(this);
```

Then I have tried to use the listener in the class::

```
pushBtn.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)
    {
        // if more than one call, change this code
        int callId = 0;
        for (SipCallSession callInfo : callsInfo)
        {
            callId = callInfo.getCallId();
            Log.e(TAG, "" + callInfo.getCallId());

        }
        final int id = callId;
        switch (event.getAction())
        {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            {

                // press
                pushBtn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.btn_blue_glossy);
                pushBtn.setChecked(true);
                OnDtmf(id, 17, 10);
                OnDtmf(id, 16, 9);

                return true;
            }
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            {

                // release
                pushBtn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.btn_lightblue_glossy);
                pushBtn.setChecked(false);
                OnDtmf(id, 18, 11);
                OnDtmf(id, 18, 11);

                return true;
            }
            default:
                return false;
        }
    }

});
```

I have multiple errors, it says `onTouch` is not implemented, but I have done so?
Also I placed the listener in the class and it now complains about the method before it saying:

```
Syntax error on token "}", delete this token
```

But That was fine until I added the listener, does a listener have to be in a method or something?

At the end of my listener I get the error:

```
Syntax error, insert "}" to complete MethodBody
```

But I do now know why.

***EDIT UPDATE***

Here is my onCreate, I get a `nullpointerexception`:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


        //handler.setActivityInstance(this);
        Log.d(THIS_FILE, "Create in call");
        setContentView(R.layout.in_call_main);

        SipCallSession initialSession = getIntent().getParcelableExtra(SipManager.EXTRA_CALL_INFO);
        synchronized (callMutex) {
            callsInfo = new SipCallSession[1];
            callsInfo[0] = initialSession;
        }

        bindService(new Intent(this, SipService.class), connection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
        prefsWrapper = new PreferencesProviderWrapper(this);

        // Log.d(THIS_FILE, "Creating call handler for " +
        // callInfo.getCallId()+" state "+callInfo.getRemoteContact());
        powerManager = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
        wakeLock = powerManager.newWakeLock(PowerManager.SCREEN_BRIGHT_WAKE_LOCK
                | PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP | PowerManager.ON_AFTER_RELEASE,
                "com.csipsimple.onIncomingCall");
        wakeLock.setReferenceCounted(false);


        takeKeyEvents(true);

        // Cache findViews
        mainFrame = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.mainFrame);
        inCallControls = (InCallControls) findViewById(R.id.inCallControls);
        inCallAnswerControls = (InCallAnswerControls) findViewById(R.id.inCallAnswerControls);
        activeCallsGrid = (InCallInfoGrid) findViewById(R.id.activeCallsGrid);
        heldCallsGrid = (InCallInfoGrid) findViewById(R.id.heldCallsGrid);
        pushBtn = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.PTT_button3);
        //pushBtn.setOnTouchListener((OnTouchListener) this);
        attachVideoPreview();

        inCallControls.setOnTriggerListener(this);
        inCallAnswerControls.setOnTriggerListener(this);

        if(activeCallsAdapter == null) {
            activeCallsAdapter = new CallsAdapter(true);
        }
        activeCallsGrid.setAdapter(activeCallsAdapter);


        if(heldCallsAdapter == null) {
            heldCallsAdapter = new CallsAdapter(false);
        }
        heldCallsGrid.setAdapter(heldCallsAdapter);


        ScreenLocker lockOverlay = (ScreenLocker) findViewById(R.id.lockerOverlay);
        lockOverlay.setActivity(this);
        lockOverlay.setOnLeftRightListener(this);

        /*
        middleAddCall = (Button) findViewById(R.id.add_call_button);
        middleAddCall.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                onTrigger(ADD_CALL, null);
            }
        });
        if (!prefsWrapper.getPreferenceBooleanValue(SipConfigManager.SUPPORT_MULTIPLE_CALLS)) {
            middleAddCall.setEnabled(false);
            middleAddCall.setText(R.string.not_configured_multiple_calls);
        }
        */

        // Listen to media & sip events to update the UI
        registerReceiver(callStateReceiver, new IntentFilter(SipManager.ACTION_SIP_CALL_CHANGED));
        registerReceiver(callStateReceiver, new IntentFilter(SipManager.ACTION_SIP_MEDIA_CHANGED));
        registerReceiver(callStateReceiver, new IntentFilter(SipManager.ACTION_ZRTP_SHOW_SAS));

        proximityManager = new CallProximityManager(this, this, lockOverlay);
        keyguardManager = KeyguardWrapper.getKeyguardManager(this);

        dialFeedback = new DialingFeedback(this, true);

        if (prefsWrapper.getPreferenceBooleanValue(SipConfigManager.PREVENT_SCREEN_ROTATION)) {
            setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
        }

        if (quitTimer == null) {
            quitTimer = new Timer("Quit-timer");
        }


        useAutoDetectSpeaker = prefsWrapper.getPreferenceBooleanValue(SipConfigManager.AUTO_DETECT_SPEAKER);

        applyTheme();
        proximityManager.startTracking();

        inCallControls.setCallState(initialSession);
        inCallAnswerControls.setCallState(initialSession);




        pushBtn.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                //if more than one call, change this code
              int callId = 0;
              for (SipCallSession callInfo : callsInfo) {
                  callId = callInfo.getCallId();
                  Log.e(TAG, ""+callInfo.getCallId());

              }
              final int id= callId;
                switch (event.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {

                    //press
                    pushBtn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.btn_blue_glossy);
                    pushBtn.setChecked(true);
                    OnDtmf(id, 17, 10);
                    OnDtmf(id, 16, 9);

                    return true;
                }
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: {

                    //release
                    pushBtn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.btn_lightblue_glossy);
                    pushBtn.setChecked(false);
                    OnDtmf(id, 18, 11); 
                    OnDtmf(id, 18, 11);

                    return true;
                }
                default:
                    return false;
                }
            }

        });




    }
```

[image]

The line with the nullpointer 250 is `pushBtn.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {`

Comment: because there's a missing `}` you are not closing the method onTouch

Comment: I try this and there is still an error, I thought the bracket count was correct already?

Comment: buddy dont implement onTouchListner() to your class as you are binding it with the view itself... try removing the implements from the class..

Comment: @BhavinNattar Then in onCreate do i ahve to say? ` pushBtn.setOnTouchListener((OnTouchListener) this);`

Comment: @Paul no! you're right! i formatted your code and saw that there are no missing brackets.

Comment: Thanks, this is why i do not understand There is something wrong about what I am doing, but I can't see what

Comment: Please post the entire class. Maybe there is a bracket too much or missing in the rest of the class.

Comment: @Paul: if you are implementing ontouchlisterner then you have to do so.. otherwise do `pushBtn.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener()...` in your oncreate..

Comment: @DaanOlislagers http://pastebin.com/FQ56a2eT here you go! Is it because the lsitener has to be in onCreate?

Comment: @BhavinNattar I put it in onCreate and there are no errors but I get a nullPointerException when i run the program.

Comment: @paul: write your `pushBtn.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener()...` lines after `pushBtn = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.PTT_button3);`

Comment: @BhavinNattar I have done so but get the nullpointerexception

Comment: @Paul: buddy do one thing post the new error log here..

Comment: @BhavinNattar I posted a screenshot of it thanks :) http://i.stack.imgur.com/tJlWW.png

Comment: @Paul: what is in your 258th line in your activity class..??

Comment: @BhavinNattar Do you mean 250th line? it is `pushBtn.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40000/discussion-between-bhavin-nattar-and-paul)

Answer (score 0):

You should add '}' on closing touch method.

Comment: I counted the brackets and this does not seem to be the case?

Comment: I have updated the OP with onCreate code and also the error, it is a nullpointerexception now

Comment: PAST FULL ERROR MEAASGE THERE ARE SO MANY REASION FOR NULL POINTER EXCEPTION

Comment: I did I posted a picture

Comment: the line 250 that it complains about is `pushBtn.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {`

Comment: your activity is not being start ,first go to emulator setting ->app-> uninstall app from there 

now clean your project and run :)

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse sometimes makes some mistakes by itself.

You're code seems right, try to cut all of your code and then paste it again in the same position.

Also try to remove all of the import at the beginning of the class and then reimporting everything by pressing

ctrl + SHIFT + o (cmd+shift+o on a mac)

another solution is to put a

```
return false;
```

at the very end of the onTouch method